Is town named Zycki located in Poland or Russia today?
My Grandparents came through Ellis Island in 1910. The records show they were from Zycki, Russia.
Does anyone know where that is today?

There's Życk/Zyck, close to Warsaw. It was in the Russian part of partitioned Poland.

FamilySearch places says it is: Poland, Masovia, Gostynin, Słubice, Zyck Polski

As has been commented elsewhere, this "user" appears to be posting AI-generated content.
